# Creating table within multi-dimensional arrays elements and drawing it

Tags: lua, lua-table, love2d

I'm trying to make array of enemies and draw it, but i keep getting errors, if it is not about array itself its about bad argument in draw function: main.lua:38:bad argument#2 to 'rectangle'(number expected, got nil)
Can anyone please explain what i'm doing wrong here is it use of generic for ?

Array code:

```
enemies = {}
for i=0,7 do
    enemies[i] = {}
    for j=0,2 do
        enemy = {}
        enemy.width = 40
        enemy.height = 20
        enemy.x = i * (enemy.width + 60) + 100
        enemy.y = enemy.height + 100
        table.insert(enemies[i],enemy)
    end

end
end
```

Draw function:

```
--enemy
love.graphics.setColor(0,255,255,255)
for i,v in ipairs(enemies) do
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill", v.x, v.y, v.width, v.height)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
enemies = {}
for i=1,8 do
    for j=1,3 do
        local enemy = {}
        enemy.width = 40
        enemy.height = 20
        enemy.x = i * (enemy.width + 60) + 100
        enemy.y = enemy.height + 100
        table.insert(enemies, enemy)
    end

end
```

I don't know, if that's what you intended though. Anyway, the reason why you got nil is that in your version `ipairs` return another table that contained three instances of `enemy`. For your version to work, you would have to add another `ipairs`:

```
for i,v in ipairs(enemies) do
    for _,e in ipairs(v) do
        love.graphics.rectangle("fill", e.x, e.y, e.width, e.height)
    end
end
```

Please remember to use `local` for function temporaries. And Lua arrays start at 1, not 0.

Comment: Thank you it works and with few tweaks displays 3 rows, only problem is im missing one column of enemies.